# Promise not completing function before going into next

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, shelljs

I am writing a promise, where the first part of my promise is doing a `git clone` in shelljs (node.js app). The second part of the promise is doing a `git pull` and more. But many times the promise starts the clone and then before that is over, jumps into the function holding other shell.js executions like `git pull`. But then it does not find the repo. What am I missing here?

My code:

```
let myPromise = new Promise((rev, err) => {
                    console.log('create promise');
                    rev();
                });

myPromise.then(() => {
                                shell.cd(' ..');
                                shell.cd('git_folder');
                                fs.access('git_repo', function(error) {
                                    if (error) {
                                        console.log("Directory does not exist.")
                                        shell.exec(`git clone the_git_repo && echo "cloned"`);

                                    } else console.log("Directory exists.");
                                })
                            }).then(() => nextFunc());

const nextFunc = () => {
    shell.cd('git_repo');
    shell.exec('git pull');
    //other git commands
}
```

Sometimes my promise runs in order, and other times, it starts the clone and goes into the `nextFunc` function but does not find the `git_repo` folder. Is there anyway to finish the clone and only then execute `nextFunc`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the main `then` callback doesn't return a promise, so the promise returned by that `then()` is immediately resolved, when the `fs.access` callback hasn't executed yet.

You should have a promise that resolves when `access` has done its asynchronous task. For that you can use `fs.promises`: it exposes the same methods (like `access`) but returning a promise instead of taking a callback.

So that part of the code can be:

```
myPromise.then(() => {
    shell.cd('..');
    shell.cd('git_folder');
    return fs.promises.access('git_repo');
}).then(() => {
    console.log("Directory exists.");
}).catch(error => {
    console.log("Directory does not exist.");
    shell.exec(`git clone the_git_repo && echo "cloned"`);
}).then(nextFunc);
```

Comment: Any feedback to this answer?